# Linear momentum of a Weyl spinor

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, field-theory, lorentz-symmetry, spinors

Let's say we have a left-handed Weyl spinor as follows:

\begin{equation}
\chi = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \end{pmatrix} 
\end{equation}

where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are complex components. What are the operators for linear momentum components ($P_{x}, P_{y}$ and $P_{z}$)? So, to be more clear, I'm referring to linear momentum operators in matrix format (so that one can calculate linear momentum based on $\alpha$ and $\beta$). Also, how does one calculate the mass for this spinor (based on $\alpha$ and $\beta$)?

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to answer your question since the things are not at all you probably think. The momentum cannot be expressed in the components $\alpha$ and $\beta$ at all.

Having said that, nevertheless I guess what you probably want to know. The momentum operator cannot be expressed by components of the Weyl-spinor, but can 
applied on it. Of course for doing it, it has to be done in a Lorentz-invariant way. To this purpose formal parts of Spinor-algebra has to be used. In the following I assume that the relativistic theory is applied. Then one would denote a left-handed Weyl-spinor by 2-component object which transforms under Lorentz-transformations as an undotted spinor $\xi^A$. To this spinor a differential operator $\partial_{A\dot{X}} = \sigma^i_{A\dot{X}}\partial_i$ can be applied, giving an expression like $ \partial_{A\dot{X}} \xi^A$ (indices appearing twice in an expression are summed over --- Einstein's summation convention).
The matrices $\sigma^i_{A\dot{X}}$ (i=0,1,2,3) are 4 2x2 matrices identical with "extended" Pauli-matrices $(1,\vec{\sigma})$ and $\partial_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ (i=0,1,2,3), the latter operator is related to the 4-momentum operator by $p_i =-i\not h\partial_i$.
So one can also write $-i\not h \partial_{A\dot{X}} \xi^A  =-i\not h  \sigma^i_{A\dot{X}}\partial_i\xi^A = \sigma^i_{A\dot{X}}p_i \xi^A$. Some sources finally define $\sigma^i_{A\dot{X}}p_i=:p_{A\dot{X}}$ which is a 2x2 matrix filled up with (complex) linear combinations of components of the 4-momentum vector which can be applied on $\xi^A$. May be this is what you refer to in your question.

Finally, having a particle described by a left-handed Weyl-spinor does not tell anything about its mass. The mass cannot computed from $\xi^A$. However, again I guess what you might mean. There might be particles existing which fulfill the Weyl-equation which is $ \partial_{A\dot{X}} \xi^A=0$, however, your spinor could also fulfill the Majorama equation: $ \partial_{A\dot{X}} \xi^A=m \xi_{\dot{X}}$ or even none of both.

So the mass $m$ could take any positive or zero value. Neither we know if particles which follow the Weyl- or Majorama-equation exist.